# How to draw on Canvas (android)

Tags: android, delphi, canvas, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I want to draw something on canvas from another method. But I can't.

```
 unit MainFormUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects, System.Math.Vectors;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  Canvas.Fill.Color := $FF111111 + random($FFFFFF);
  Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
  Canvas.FillRect(RectF(random(300), random(300), random(300), random(300)), 0,
    0, [], 1);
  Canvas.EndScene;
end;

end.
```

It doesn't draw anything. Why? Please, without using drawing operations in OnPaint method.

Comment: On windows it works perfect

Comment: I can't test myself, so I just comment: Change the drawing code to the forms `OnPaint` event. Then change the `OnTimer` event to simply call `Invalidate` only. If this works, I can add an answer wth explanation.

Comment: So drawings should do another class. I send to that class Canvas of the form. Then this class try to draw on this canvas but unseccessfully

Comment: You *must* use the `OnPaint` event of the parent of the canvas you want to draw on.

Comment: But on windows it works perfect. Why i can't do so on andoid?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work perfectly on Windows either! Using the taskbar button, minimize and restore the window. The drawn rectangle disappears.

Comment: In game with fullscreen 60 fps it doesn't matter. It updates instantly

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my first comment, or are we just quibbling and stomping the floor here?

Comment: Possibly, it will work. But i need to draw on canvas from another class with some data (or any other ways to display BitMap/draw bitmap on canvas as fast as possible (and working) not in OnPaint method)

Comment: If you don't want advice, then why ask us? You've already decided on the solution. Go ahead and do it your way then.

Answer (score -1):

```
  if Canvas.BeginScene the
  begin
    Canvas.Fill.Color := $FF111111 + random($FFFFFF);
    Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.FillRect(RectF(random(300), random(300), random(300), random(300)), 
    0,
    0, [], 1);
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
```